# JQueryAjax function at more places

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an html page with these elements

```
<DIV ID="PI"><div id="selection1"  style="display: table-row;">
                PI CODE:<input id="ecode" type="text" name="ecode" onblur="loadEname(this.value);" value="<?php echo $code; ?>">
                PI Name:<input id="ename" type="text" name="ename" readonly>
            </div>
        </DIV>
       <DIV ID="CO_PI"><div id="selection2"  style="display: table-row;">
                CO PI CODE:<input id="ecode" type="text" name="ecode" onblur="loadEname(this.value);" >
                CO PI Name:<input id="ename" type="text" name="ename" readonly>
            </div>
        </DIV>
```

and a JQuery Ajax function

```
function loadEname(str) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../PhpProject1/UserNameCheck.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"ecode": str},
        //data: "ecode="+ str,
        success: function(response) {
            //alert(response.ename);
            $('#ename').val(response.ename);
        },
        error: function(x, e) {
            if (x.status == 0) {
                alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
            } else if (x.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested URL not found.');
            } else if (x.status == 500) {
                alert('Internel Server Error - Please try after relogin to the application');
            } else if (e == 'parsererror') {
                alert('Parsing JSON Request failed.');
            } else if (e == 'timeout') {
                alert('Request Time out.');
            } else {
                alert('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and a php page for getting result from database.The result is in the form of json.key with ename and value with corresponding value from database.
but here in my html page the id=ename of selection1 div shows the result but id=ename of selection2  will not get the result to ename id but it goes to to selection1.how to solve this ?thank you in advance

Comment: ID's should be unique...!

Comment: if i will change the id..one will work..i want get the result in multiple places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID's should be unique, so remove `id=ename` from your inputs, and do something like:

```
....
<input id="ecode" type="text" name="ecode" onblur="loadEname(this);" value="<?php echo $code; ?>">
...
```

js part

```
function loadEname(obj) {
    var str = obj.value,
        curEle = obj;
    $.ajax({
        url: '../PhpProject1/UserNameCheck.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"ecode": str},
        //data: "ecode="+ str,
        success: function(response) {
            //alert(response.ename);
            $(curEle).next('input[name="ename"]').val(response.ename);
        },
      ....
```